# Date and simpledateformat, wrong output

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

so if  print 01/18/2013 i get JUNE 01, 2014 or if i print 08/18/2013 i get JUNE 08, 2014
What should i change to get correct output in English format date?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date givenDate = formatter.parse(s);
        SimpleDateFormat formatterprint = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(formatterprint.format(givenDate).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: You'll have to give a sample of the data you're parsing before we can help.

Comment: Do you want "January 18, 2013" from "01/18/2013"?

Comment: rgettman, yes, so if print 08/18/2014 i will get AUG 18, 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern used to parse the date is `dd,MM,yyyy`, which means day followed by a comma, followed by month, followed by a comma, followed by year.

You enter `08/18/2013`. 08 is a valid day, but 18 isn't a valid month. And you should enter commas, not slashes.

Since you enter 18/2013 as the month, it's interpreted as the 18th month of 2013, which corresponds to the 6th month of 2014 (since years, well, have only 12 months): June.

Comment: i edited my code few times, sorry, forgeted to change it also in post.